# NativeScript View _createUI Accessing Canvas?

Tags: android-canvas, nativescript

I Would like to access the Canvas Via NativeScript, But i cant seem to find the bridging entry point. as _CreateUI does not pass in the canvas, where onDraw in Java does.

i would like to do the NativeScript Equiv of:

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    // floor the border width to avoid gaps between the border and the image 
    float roundedBorderWidth = (float) Math.floor(this.borderWidth); 
    float innerRadius = Math.max(0, this.cornerRadius - roundedBorderWidth); 

    // The border width is included in the padding so there is no need for 
    // clip if there is no inner border radius. 
    if (innerRadius != 0) { 
        this.rect.set( 
                roundedBorderWidth, 
                roundedBorderWidth,  
                this.getWidth() - roundedBorderWidth,  
                this.getHeight() - roundedBorderWidth); 

        this.path.reset(); 
        this.path.addRoundRect(rect, innerRadius, innerRadius, android.graphics.Path.Direction.CW); 

        canvas.clipPath(this.path); 
    } 

    super.onDraw(canvas); 
}
```

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick sample on how to construct the *Canvas* in a NativeScript Android app. Using the [*Placeholder* component](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder) with NativeScript to create the native component, unless you want to write a plugin/module, then you'd take a different approach entirely.

XML:

```
<Page> <Placeholder creatingView="createCanvas" height="200" /> </Page>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function createCanvas(args) {
     var canvas = new android.graphics.Canvas(); // construct an empty canvas
     args.view = canvas; // this puts the canvas on the interface where the placeholder is.
}
exports createCanvas = createCanvas;`
```

Comment: mmm, now that's interesting, as I have just released 1 plugin on npm, what way would you suggest in doing this as a plugin?

Comment: If you create a plugin for others to consume or to reuse then follow several of my plugins for nativescript as a good guide. Here is a good one that utilizes the *createUI()* function. https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-gif

Comment: Hi brad, can you please guide me for how to use "android.graphics.Bitmap"  in nativescript. I want to create bitmap using Bitmap class, but didn't find any docs. Thank you!

Comment: @OnkarNene open a question on SO with at least some context of what you want and maybe a code snippet of an attempt and I'll be glad to help :)

Comment: @BradMartin please do check link and let me know the solution :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724634/nativescript-bitmap-canvas